# looking for best way for string manipulation

Tags: c#

I m looking for for some best way for string manipulation. Below is the expacted output,

`[System/EventID=100 or System/EventID=108]`, commutative string should starts with `[` and end with `]` plus has to remove extra `or` in between?

```
try
{
    string systemEvents = string.Empty;
    var eventIds = "100,108".Split(',');

    systemEvents += "[";

    foreach (var eventId in eventIds)
    {
        systemEvents += "System/EventID=" + eventId + " or ";
    }

    var X = systemEvents.Remove(systemEvents.Length - 4).Trim();

    var Y = X + "]";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: What are you asking? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Is this question about string concatenation in a tight loop vs string builder vs string join?

Comment: I hope it's not [The Sad Tragedy of Micro-Optimization Theater](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/). Because

Comment: @ Drag and Drop, it's not. Thanks for sharing the article

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make use of available string handling functions like [`String.Format()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397701.aspx)(*which replace specified format items with the text representation of the corresponding object values.*) and [`String.Join()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx)(*Concatenates a specified separator String between each element of a specified String array, yielding a single concatenated string.*) to do this work. Try the following snippet, also Check a Working Example [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4HXt3b)

```
string eventIdStr = String.Join(" or ", eventIds.Select(x=> "System/EventID=" +x))
string systemEvents = String.Format("[{0}]",eventIdStr);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var s = string.Format("[{0}]", string.Join(" or ", "100,108".Split(',').Select(x=> "System/EventID=" + x));
```